# Uniform convergence of a double sequence $f_n(x)$

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function for each $n$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 0}f_n(x) = k$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x).$$
Moreover, the first convergence above is non-increasing, and the second is non-decreasing.

Is there any way to conclude that $f_n(x) \to k$ as $x \to 0$ converges **uniformly** in $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Definition of **Uniform Convergence** is state for converging a sequence of functions to specific function. It this case you can't conclude $\{f_n\}$ uniformly converges to $f$. And at just one point like $x=0$ as you try, there is no uniformly or nonuniformly convergency has meaning!

Answer (score 0):

If by
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f_n(x) = k$$ 
*uniformly* in $n$ you mean that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that, if 
$$|x| < \delta(\epsilon)$$
then
$$|f_n(x)-k| < \epsilon$$
**for all $n\in \Bbb N,$** then you might consider as a counterexample that satisfies your hypotheses
$$f_n(x) = 1-e^{-nx^2}, \ \ n =1,2,\dots$$
(you can restrict it in $[0,1]$ if you prefer). We have
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f_n(x) =0^+,$$
$$f_{n+1}(x) \geq f_n(x),$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x) = f(x),$$
with 
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & (x\neq 0)\\
0 & (x=0).
\end{cases}
$$